# open csv format in excel while igoniring ;

Tags: excel, csv

I have Java program that is used to write data in the csv file. The problem that I have i following:

I have same function that I want to call in Excel when I open csv file, but the function contains ";" as a seperator between values, so my function always get dividen in to smaller parts that have no meaning,

So my question is. How can I write a forumla in csv so that Excel knows if that is seperator or not.

I tried Setting the whole function betwee "" but the function still got divided.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you open a .csv file in Excel "straight away", i.e. by double click or using Open File dialog, Excel assumes the list separator (usually `,` or `;`) set is regional settings (Control Panel / Region and Language / Additional Settings... / List Separator). You can change this value, then restart Excel to see the effect.

The other way is to use Data / From Text dialog in Excel. You can choose Delimited -> Other delimiter to specify any delimiting character you like.